# How to Process file on S3 event through AWS lambda using C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking for C# code blocks to read file from S3 on PUT event and upload the file to another bucket. I am fairly new to C# and see most of the blogs are either written for python and java. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I know it's too late but maybe this will help someone else.
You need to add Amazon.Lambda.S3Events Nuget package. See code, this is how your Lambda Function should look like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.S3Events;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;

public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var s3Event = evnt.Records?[0].S3;
    if(s3Event == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        var destinationBucketName = "your_bucket_to_upload";
        var destinationKey= "folder/subfolder/fileName.txt";

        var s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
        var request = new CopyObjectRequest
        {
            SourceBucket = s3Event.Bucket.Name,
            SourceKey = s3Event.Object.Key,
            DestinationBucket = destinationBucketName,
            DestinationKey = destinationKey
        };
        
        var response = await s3.CopyObjectAsync(request);
        return response.HttpStatusCode.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine($"Error getting object {s3Event.Object.Key} from bucket {s3Event.Bucket.Name}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.");
        context.Logger.LogLine(e.Message);
        context.Logger.LogLine(e.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }
}
```

You can find AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-package-toolkit.html

Comment: `S3Event ` FTW 

Answer (score 0):

The flow would be:

- Configure an **Amazon S3 Event to trigger the AWS Lambda function** when a new object is created
- Details of the object created will be passed to the Lambda function via the `event`
- Your Lambda function should then call [`CopyObject()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3CopyObjectCopyObjectRequest.html) to duplicate the object to another bucket (no need to download/upload)

See also: [Copying Objects - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsExamples.html)

Comment: I was able to implement S3 event in C# .Net Core 2.1, however some of custom .DLLs are using VisualBasic function intensively and due to same reason i cant use .Net core 2.1. Could you please assist me how to call S3 event function in the main function of Custom .Net Core 3.0?

Comment: You might want to create a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bucket and create IAM role that has access to the bucket you created. Assign to that role to your lambda function ( either thru AWS console or AWS SDK if you use Visual studio. the option is available in the following screenshot1)

[image]

After you published go to the Event Trigger tab and add the bucket you created. Make sure you upload the code again once you set this trigger

[image]

Upload a file and check from the cloud watch log to see function has executed. Some sample code is attached here
[image]