# Cannot send message from Lambda to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I need to only send specific files that contains specific attribute(metadata) from my s3 bucket to SQS. I am not sure what is the best way to do that. Since SQS does not have a filter option nor SNS.

EDIT: I followed the directions and connected lambda with s3 to send messages in sqs, but there is still something wrong. SQS says "Message in Flight" instead of message received. I can't see the message when I poll for messages.

```
public async Task<SendMessageResponse> FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        Task<SendMessageResponse> sendMessageResponse;
        var s3Event = evnt.Records?[0].S3;
        try
        {
            var meta = "x-amz-meta-ml-score";
            SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest();
            var response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);
            
            

            foreach (string metadata in response.Metadata.Keys)
            {
                if (metadata == meta)
                {
                    sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl = myQueueUrl;
                    sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = evnt.ToString();
                    sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = s3Event.ToString();
                    //sendMessageResponse = await SQSCleint.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest);
                }
            }
            

            return await this.SQSCleint.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Error getting object {s3Event.Object.Key} from bucket {s3Event.Bucket.Name}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.");
            context.Logger.LogLine(e.Message);
            context.Logger.LogLine(e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that Amazon S3 metadata can be used for subscription filtering in Amazon SNS. Do you have any documentation that suggests this is possible? Normally, subscription filtering is done based on **message attributes** that are supplied when the message is sent to SNS.

Comment: Is there any other way I can filter incoming messages from s3?

Comment: You could configure the Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function, and the Lambda function can examine the object and then decide whether to take an action (eg sending a message to SQS or processing the file itself). Feel free to edit your question to provide more information about the larger goal you are trying to achieve (that is, _why_ you want to filter based on files).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like I might be able to use it. Could you please attach an example of Lambda code in c# of how I can examine the object and only send to SQS based on certain attributes?

Comment: There is some relevant code in [How to Process file on S3 event through AWS lambda using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60663806/174777). Given the bucket name and object key, the Lambda function could call `HeadObject()` to retrieve object metadata. Then it could use `SendMessage()` to send an appropriate message to an Amazon SQS queue.

Comment: I edited my question according to you suggestion. Could you please take a look at it and see if you can find out if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: 'In-flight' means that something is consuming the message from the SQS queue, but is not deleting the message. Make sure you haven't incorrectly configured the Lambda function to trigger from SQS (it should trigger from s3). _Something_ is retrieving messages from the queue. (It might even be you looking at the message details in the console.)